# Can't find the AJAX for the price in Tmall

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to get the promo-price (289) from the following URL

https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a220m.1000858.1000725.8.71f45847627RnZ&id=534345441395&skuId=3690108903807&standard=1&user_id=2416562551&cat_id=2&is_b=1&rn=d2c6de98dcc3fda21b653717e8ecee86

I've read a little about AJAX and did some searching for DOM requests, but I'm unable to find a way to get the price.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import requests

req = requests.request('GET', 'https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a220m.1000858.1000725.1.3cbf57249BnKrJ&id=44577700416&skuId=99684796823&standard=1&user_id=330802957&cat_id=2&is_b=1&rn=f7f06abb46583e8c1fca47f5ba972f43')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all(class_='tm-price')
```

Comment: can you provide the soup response ?? i can read it its require login

Comment: the soup returns [ ]

Comment: The url wich you have provide redirects to a login page, so you cant find the price becuase Beautiful Soup is pull out data of the login page and not from the page you want, i suggest you to use mechanize to login, and then pass the data to Beautiful Soup